# Any ideas why this code won't work

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have multiple files with names and stats and a file that checks for a certain stat.

```
Example File 1
Eddy,23,2,4,9,AB
Frank,46,2,4,5,DA

Example File 2
AB
B
BA
DA
DH
```

I am not getting any errors but it is not writing to the new file.

The code I am using to do this is:

```
# Open Removal file and create a set of required removals
book_removals = open("File2.csv")
search_removals_col = 0

# Open the All Candidates file
book_candidates = open('File1.csv')
search_candidates_col = 4

# Create a New Roster file
book_new = open('upload.csv')

# Iterate through candidates file, looking for removals
for row in range(search_candidates_col):
if book_candidates == book_removals:
    book_new.write(row)
    book_new.flush
book_new.close()
```

Comment: The indentation for the `if` looks odd. Does your code actually look like that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `book_new.flush()` instead of `book_new.flush`? Also, if you don't specify the mode when opening the file, it will be `read`-mode by default. Since you want to write in your file, you should go with `book_new = open('upload.csv', 'w')`. And `book_removals` is a file handle, when comparing to this variable you are not looking at what the file contains.

Comment: What do you expect the test `book_candidates == book_removals` to indicate?

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies I am basically looking for it to compare column 5 in file1 to file2 column 1 if it is in file2 to then copy the row to a new fiile

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
stats = set()
with open('File2.csv') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        stats.add(line)
with open('File1.csv', newline='') as file1:
    file1_reader = csv.reader(file1)
    with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='') as output:
        output_writer = csv.writer(output)
        for line in file1_reader:
            if any(item in stats for item in line):
                 output_writer.writerow(line)
```

When dealing with .csv files, use the `csv` module.  This builds a `set` out of lines in `File2`, then goes through every line in `File1`.  If that line has a value from `File2`, then that line is written to `output.csv`

Comment: Hey Patrick thanks for the reply apologies for delay. As you have guessed I am pretty new to python so do i set stats to the column in question?

Comment: Okay tested this code and the file is still coming back with ouput file empty even though I know my file1 has entries of file2

Comment: Hmm.  `print(stats)` before opening File1 and make sure everything's inside it.

Comment: okay tested and seeing correct stats to search for.and it is creating a output file but is still empty grr lol

Comment: Try adding `print(line)` before the conditional in the last for loop.  Maybe the line's are getting chopped up oddly

Comment: As a string or as a list of strings?

Comment: just tried print(line) after the sequence and nothing shows :S

Comment: as a string just one word

Comment: it won't let me direct this discussion to chat as low level

Comment: still no difference lol driving me crazyif you have an e-mail i could e-mail you?

Comment: Your best bet is to probably make a new question here.  The problem is that `csv.reader` should be splitting the `line` into a list of strings.  I suppose you could do that yourself by replacing the conditional with `if any(item in stats for item in line.split(','))`